# Como utilizar la variable de una función en otra función en python?

Tags: python, funciones, variables

hola amigos buenos días.
Tengo una inquietud de como puedo utilizar una variable que se crea en una función, dentro de otra función.

tengo lo siguiente:
una primera función que crea una variable driver:

```
def driver_google(ruta_descarga):
separador = os.path.sep
ruta_driver = os.path.join(separador.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split(separador)[:-1]),'chromedriver.exe')
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory" :f"{ruta_descarga}",})
#llamado al driver con la nueva ruta de descargas
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = f'{ruta_driver}', chrome_options= chromeOptions)
return driver
```

y luego deseo declarar otra función en la cual necesito utilizar la variable driver.

```
def demanda_energia_7():
#ruta para descargar achivo
descarga = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "07_Demanda de Energia")
driver_google(descarga)
driver.maximize_window()
```

pero en el editor de codigo VSC. me sale la alerta que en esta segunda función, **driver** no esta definida.
Mi pregunta es como puedo realizar el llamado de esta variable en las demás funciones que estoy creado?
Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe buenos dias.  De antemano muchas gracias por tu ayuda y por responder la pregunta.  Si entendí bien tu comentario hice lo siguiente: dendro de la función def demanda_energia_7(driver), cree una variable que llama a la función driver_google, de la siguiente manera:
driver = driver_google(descarga)
pero esto me genera el siguiente error:  demanda_energia_7() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En situaciones como ésta, donde múltiples funciones deben compartir recursos creados por otras funciones, el patrón a usar es tener un `main` que crea los recursos, pasandolos a las funciones que los necesiten.

```
def driver_google(ruta_descarga):
    separador = os.path.sep
    ruta_driver = os.path.join(separador.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split(separador)[:-1]),'chromedriver.exe')
    chromeOptions = Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory" :f"{ruta_descarga}",})
    #llamado al driver con la nueva ruta de descargas
    driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = f'{ruta_driver}', chrome_options= chromeOptions)
    return driver

def demanda_energia_7(driver):
    #ruta para descargar achivo
    descarga = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "07_Demanda de Energia")
    driver.maximize_window()
    
# Aqui va el main
driver = driver_google("una ruta")
demanda_energia_7(driver)
```

Comment: Hola @candid Moe, muchas gracias por responder y ayudarme en esta situación.  Entiendo lo que me menciones.  sin embargo debo hacer el llamado a la función driver_google, dentro de la función demanda_enerigia_7, (y las demás funciones que utilizo) ya que la variable ruta_descarga, es diferente en cada función.  
Si utilizo la opción que mencionas de la variable driver en el main, debo hacer n veces  la variable driver cambiando la ruta, antes de ejecutar las funciones que la utiliza.  Mi pregunta seria si no es posible dentro de la función demanda energia hacer el llamado

Comment: Puedes llamar a `demanda_energia_7` pasando `ruta_descarga` (en lugar de driver) como parámetro, e instanciar `driver` dentro. Sin ver la app completa no puedo recomendar una alternativa o la otra.

Comment: hola @candid Moe, asi lo hice.... muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudo bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es recibir un parámetro en tu función `demanda_energia_7()`, algo como:

```
def demanda_energia_7(driver):
    #ruta para descargar achivo
    descarga = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "07_Demanda de Energia")
    driver_google(descarga)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Entonces para enviarle el resultado de tu variable driver que retornas en la función anterior, hay 2 formas de hacerlo:

1. Enviando directamente el resultado de la función con la misma función:

```
demanda_energia_7(driver_google(ruta_descarga))
```

2. Obteniendo el resultado de tu driver y enviárselo por separado a tu definición que utilizara el driver:

```
driver = driver_google(ruta_descarga)
    
demanda_energia_7(driver)
```

Comment: Hola @Marcos Guerrero.   Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Pero me queda una inquietud en las 2 opciones que me menciones y es la siguiente:  la funcion driver_google utiliza la variable ruta_descarga, es variable siempre estará dentro de la función demanda_energía (y otras funciones que necesito crear), al estar dentro de la funcion mi inquietud es como pasarla.  Hice lo siguiente dentro la funcion demanda_energia
driver = driver_google(descarga), pero me genera error:  demanda_energia_7() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar `driver` como variable global:

```
def driver_google(ruta_descarga):
    separador = os.path.sep
    ruta_driver = os.path.join(
        separador.join(
            os.path.dirname(
                os.path.abspath(__file__)
            ).split(separador)[:-1]
        ),
        'chromedriver.exe'
    )
    chromeOptions = Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option(
        "prefs",
        {"download.default_directory" :f"{ruta_descarga}",}
    )
    #llamado al driver con la nueva ruta de descargas
    global driver
    driver =  webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path = f'{ruta_driver}',
        chrome_options= chromeOptions
    )
    return driver
```

Esto permitirá que tu variable esté disponible fuera de la función `driver_google`, y que pueda ser utilizada en cualquier otra sección posterior del código.